# Install Windows 10 on CentOS 7

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, centos-7

I'm trying this for the first time so thought of taking a suggestion from you guys before landing into any problem.

I know how to dual boot a `Linux OS` on top of Windows. But I want the other way round. I have **CentOS 7 already installed on my Desktop occupying the complete 500 GB space i.e, no other partition**. It has `8GB RAM`. I'm working on it from a couple of months and I don't wanna loose any of my work. Now I need to install `Windows 10` on the same machine. **But I don't need an extra hard disk.** I Googled it but I dint find any solution as all the sites, tutorials and videos tell me **how to install a Linux OS on top of Windows** but none tell me about the reverse way.

> I don't want the Windows on a VM, I have already thought about it and that doesn't gives me more flexibility for my task. Sorry I cant give any description on my task due to the company policies.

**So is this possible?** Sorry if I'm asking anything wrong.

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: "When you install Windows after Linux, Windows ignores Linux, doesn’t know how to resize its partitions, and overwrites the Linux boot loader with its own. You’ll have to repair the Linux system’s boot loader before you can boot back into your Linux system again." From http://www.pcworld.com/article/2955460/operating-systems/dual-booting-linux-with-windows-what-you-need-to-know.html

Comment: And here you can find the ways (though not easy) to got it done http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: @YisroelTech Yup that's true. Windows OS is developed in such a way that it has to be on the first part of my HDD. I should either create a USB stick which has `gparted` in it and than I can do a partition. But that's not the safe way either.

Comment: Ok the post [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) is quite convincing one. Let me give a try with VM's and than try with the actual machine.